# ¿Cuál es el orden correcto para declarar funciones en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Me gustaría saber cuál es el orden en el que se deben declarar las funciones en JavaScript, en caso de que quiera declarar varias funciones las cuales dependen de otras funciones, cual sería el orden correcto.

**Ejemplo 1**

```js
    function funcion2(){
        console.log('como estas');
    }
    
    function funcion1(){
        console.log('hola');
        funcion2();
    }
    
    button.addEventListener('click', funcion1);
```

**Ejemplo 2**

```js
    button.addEventListener('click', funcion1);
    
    function funcion1(){
        console.log('hola');
        funcion2();
    }
    
    function funcion2(){
        console.log('como estas');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de ejecutar un programa, JS inicia la etapa de **Memory Allocation**, ahi todas las variables y funciones son inicializadas.

Inicia el programa JS.

> Memory Allocation: `funcion1` y `funcion2` ya están en memoria e iniciailizadas, si escribieras en tu programa primero `funcion2` y luego `funcion1`, no impotaría, JS las pone en memoria.

Luego, en la etapa de **thread of execution**, las funciones se ejecutan según el orden en que son llamadas en la secuencia del programa.

Secuencia:

1. LLamada a funcion1 (ya esta en memoria)
2. Llamada a funcion2 anidada (ya esta en memoria)

Dicho lo anterior, no importa en que parte del programa se declaren las funciones, lo que importa es la secuencia en la que se llaman. Si una función depende de otra, el sentido común indica cuál debe llamarse primero en el código.

Finalmente, el programador decide donde declarar las funciones en un programa, lo normal es escribir una secuencia lógica tal como lo indica el colega @anythingg, esto para que sea fácil recordar lo que el programa hace y también, que otro programador lo pueda seguir, es decir que el código sea inteligible.

El tema es diferente si se usa la sintaxis **function expression**, pero eso ya es otra pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que definas la función antes de invocarla como en el ejemplo 1.

No altera la funcionalidad, ya que en los dos casos el resultado es el mismo, pero es una buena práctica definir la función antes de invocarla.